# getting value of sibling input that is dynamically created with jquery

Tags: jquery, input, siblings

I have a ajax returned value that is a json array. I then use .each() to append the values to a table. I include a button in each row to select the paticular row. How do I get the value of the sibling 'editTemplateId' to select that particular row.

heres the code

ajax call

```
   $.ajax({
        url: '/php-list/ajax/',
        type: 'POST',
        data: {method: 'loadTemplatesGrid'},    
        dataType: 'json',                         
        success: function(data){                 
            $("#templatesGridTable").find("tr:gt(0)").remove();                            

            $.each(data, function(i, item) {  
                $('#templatesGridTable > tbody:last').append('<tr><td id="templateTitle"><h4>'+item.d+'</h4></td><td><form method="post"><input type="text" name="editTemplateId" id="editTemplateId" value="'+item.a+'"><input type="button" class="submit" type="button" id="editTemplate" name="editTemplate" value="Edit Template" onclick="editTemplateClick();"></form></td></tr>');                
            });  
        }
  });
```

the jquery function(s)

this one just alerts a blank message

```
function editTemplateClick(){  
    alert($(this).siblings('#editTemplateId').val());
}
```

this one just alerts the top rows id value

```
function editTemplateClick(){  
    alert($('#editTemplateId').val());
}
```

this also just alerts a blank message

```
 function editTemplateClick(){  
    alert(  $(this).parent().find('#editTemplateId').val() );
 }
```

any help greatly appreciated

Comment: You got to pass the `$(this)` object that is clicked!

Comment: Share a fiddle link of your work, that might help us understand and debug your problem better

Comment: heres a fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/uapwn7cz/4/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
 $(document).ready(function () {
  $('#templatesGridTable').click(function (event) {
    alert($(event.target).prev().val());
  });
 });
```

found the answer myself

Answer (score 0):

You have used an id `editTemplateId` in a for loop, which will generate multiple `inputs` of same id.

As per the W3C rules the id should be unique.

Try using a class instead of id and that might fix your problem.

Here is a updated [**fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/uapwn7cz/5/)

Also for safer side use the below code

```
    //For dynamically added elements
    $(document).on('click','.editTemplate', function () {
        alert($(this).parent().find('.editTemplateId').val());
    });
```

Comment: but the class will also be duplicated. If I could make each class unique then I could make each id unique. The site is intranet so W3C is not top priority, just need to be able to get the value of the sibling input

Comment: Just try replacing the id with a class. With this fix you should get the value of the sibling input.

Comment: changing the ID to a class and alerting that also just returns the last one that was appended to the table, there are now multiple hidden inputs with a class of 'editTemplateId'

Comment: hers a js fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/uapwn7cz/4/ the table rows are added dynamically from an ajax result so cannot have unique identifiers